# How to trigger a method by triggering the return of a second page?

Tags: javascript, php, css, ajax

Page1.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <input type="hidden" value="valuetest" id="idinput">

    <div onclick="myfunction()" style="height: 30px;width: 30px;background: gray;">
        <div id="receive"></div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function myfunction() {
          $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "page2.php",
            data: {
              sendpost: $('#idinput').val()
            },
            success: function(data) {
              $('#receive').html(data);
            }
          });

         function myfunction2(){

         }

        }
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Page2.php

```
<?php
    $var = $_POST['sendpost']; //This line is not in use
    echo "return";
?>
```

This code is working perfectly! `Page1` sends the value `valuetest` to `page2` without the need to refresh the page. The `echo` of `page2` returns the value `return` to `page1` inserting this into `div="receive"`. So far so good. I want instead of having a `div="receive"` receive a value, it triggers the function `myfunction2` or any other method that allows me to style the `page1` (css).

In short: the return of `page2` should only serve to call a method of `page1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just pass your function as a success callback.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function myfunction() {
          $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "page2.php",
            data: {
              sendpost: $('#idinput').val()
            },
            success: myfunction2
          });

         function myfunction2(){

         }

        }
    </script>
```

And if you want to return a string that trigger a function, you can return the name of the function and pass it to the `eval()` function which evaluate a string.

```
// In your php
<?php
    $var = $_POST['sendpost']; //This line is not in use
    echo "myfunction2()";

// In your js

success: function(data) {
    eval(data); // Call the function returned by your PHP
}
```